# Can Java read what is happening in an Adobe Flash based game?

Tags: java, flash, automation

Quite simply as the title states, is it possible for Java to read what is happening in a web-browser based Flash game?

For Example: Could I make a Java program which could play FarmVille for me by reading what is going on currently and make decisions based on a pre-determined set of actions?

Answer (score 6):

FarmVille doesn't publish any sort of API, and you won't be able to access the RAM allocated to the Flash player (to my knowledge), so your only real course of action is to analyze the screen and automate input. In other words, there's no prewritten `farmville.getUnplowedCells()` to use, but you can write a program that takes screenshots, analyzes them to find the unplowed cells, and then generates the mouse/keyboard input that would make your character plow his unplowed cells. The [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class can be used for this sort of programming.

This would be very time consuming and probably not worth the effort. Also as a  side effect this would essentially "take control" of your mouse and keyboard and prevent you from using your computer normally. However this problem can be mitigated by running the program in a virtual machine.

Comment: Ooh, I do like this idea, as Ben also suggested. Between using this robot and having a network sniffer like JustLogin recommended I feel spoilt for choice! I agree it wouldn't be worth the effort but this would help me decimate family and friends while simultaneously getting me back into Java - win win!

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no implementation for a Java-Flash bridge that allows anything more direct than IPC. Your best bet is decompilation (which would probably require deobfuscation) of the swf and interaction through common IPC mechanisms.

You could also tackle this using a different approach by recognizing elements on the screen by their pixel colors, for that you could use the Java [Robot API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) which provides you with access to the keyboard, mouse and video. Since FarmVille is a 2D game, recognizing elements on the screen should be fairly straightforward -- performing image comparison, or partial image comparison (just the image's borders or a representative part) to increase the speed.

Aside, cheating in online games is not a nice thing to do and you can probably find activities that are more productive given you are smart enough to make software that works.

Comment: This is a great response: "Aside, cheating in online games is not a nice thing to do and you can probably find activities that are more productive given you are smart enough to make software that works." I love that line.

I get bored with the games very easily but I have lots of friends / family that play a mix of them. I enjoy programming much more and was wondering if I could combine the two. Thanks for trying to make me a better person lol :D

Comment: @Accendi Getting back to this question, what I would do if I were to make cheats for this game is decompile the SWF file and provide means of access from the loading webpage via ExternalInterface (AS3), then do automation via JavaScript (this is not Java, but that's still a programming project)

Answer (score 4):

If you goal is to make a bot for FarmVille, then you're heading a wrong way. Keep in mind: it's ONLINE game. So, you don't have to read flash client's state, it'll be much more better, to read incoming packets, you don't have to simulate mouse/keyboard events in swf - just create correct packets, discribing your in-game actions. So I recomend you act like this:

1) Write a sniffer in Java (it's quite easy, because you have to write a simple one, not an ultimate tool, like Wireshark).

2) Use request's analytic (such as Firefox's Firebug) to catch some packets from your game. Reading them, you can retrieve all info, what you need: packets headers, game actions encoding, etc.

3) Code logic in your Java program: read incoming game packets and execute actions, sending requests.

4) Set user-agent options of your connection object similar to a popular browser (if you refuse doing that, game server may ignore your requests).

That's all. Remember: a game bot isn't an image recognizer, it's just another game client, with another GUI and logic.

P.S. If I misunderstood you, and your goal is to create a webpage with flash and applet, which comunicate with each other, you have to use JavaScript as a mediator between them. Flash calls JS using ExternalInterface.call, JS calls applet and vice versa.

Comment: I figured using the graphic interface was a bit clunky and I absolutely love this idea. I've been hankering for a nice little java project to do in my spare time and this seems to fit the bill. Thanks!